# Disable/reduce time fade out animation dash

Tags: gnome, launcher, ubuntu-gnome

Is it possible to disable the fade out animation of the applications overview (dash) without using compiz and disabling all animations? I really like the animations in GNOME, but I it is really laggy when closing the applications and workspace overview. I read somewhere that this is caused by not caching the menu items. Is there a way to make that happen so that the menu will close properly? Or is their a way to disable or reduce the time of the fade out animation?

Answer (score 1):

Since GNOME 3.8 there is an explicit option to disable animations, you can change with gconf editor, or simply issue this from terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

Also if this is not enough for you or you PC, you can enhace the responsiveness of UI by reducing the animation time:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/overview.js
```

Change the ANIMATION_TIME to 0.001

```
const ANIMATION_TIME = 0.001;
```

Comment: In 15.10 there is no `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/overview.js` even creating it and adding only that line had no effect